# Trying to make a javascript account system on my page using javascript... but apparently I've overlooked something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, account

My html page seems like ignoring part of the script: when you have an account it doesn't hide the `#signup` div, and when you don't have one it doesn't hide the `#account` div: here is the JavaScript code:

```
if(localStorage.hasAnAccount){
    $('#signup').hide();
    $('#AccountName').html(localStorage.accountName)
}else{
    $('#account').hide();
}
function createNewAccount(){
    localStorage.accountName=$('#newAccountName').html();
    localStorage.accountPassword=$('newAccountPassword').html();
    if(typeof localStorage.accountName=='string'&& typeof localStorage.accountPassword=='string'){
        alert('congrats! Your account has been made!');
        localStorage.hasAnAccount=true;
    }else{
        alert('check that your name and password are alphanumeric strings');
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Account | Cicada3301's Website</title>
     <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/stylesheet.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/jquery-ui-stylesheet.css'>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.copot.eu/matei/account/account-scripts.js'></script>
    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/me.jpg'>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div id='account'>
            <div id='AccountName'></div>
        </div>
        <div id='signup'>
            <p><input type='text' id='newAccountName'> Insert your account name</p>
            <p><input type='text' id='newAccountPassword'> Insert your account password</p>
            <p><input type='button' onclick='createNewAccount()' value='Create Account'></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I think happened is that I didn't set the `localStorage` Object to be anything at first... but I have no idea how `localStorage` works other than it is an Object and in all samples of this Object I never found anyone declare the variable

If I've overlooked something else here is the link to the page: http://www.copot.eu/matei/account

|UPDATE|

after what you told me this should be the outcome, but still doesn't work:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
if (localStorage.hasAnAccount) {
    $('#signup').hide();
    $('#AccountName').html(localStorage.accountName)
} else {
    $('#account').hide();
}

$('#createNewAccount').click(

function () {
    if (typeof localStorage.accountName == 'string' && typeof localStorage.accountPassword == 'string') {
        localStorage.accountName = $('#newAccountName').val();
        localStorage.accountPassword = $('newAccountPassword').val();

        alert('congrats! Your account has been made!');
        localStorage.hasAnAccount = true;
    } else {
        alert('check that your name and password are alphanumeric strings');
    }
});
})
```

Comment: Wrap your script in `document.ready`.

Comment: @Mathew Nope, still doesn't work (the webpage is still the same... but rapped the script in $(document).ready(function(){SCRIPT}))

Comment: @Milkywayspatterns it runs the alert: I checked

Comment: @Sudhir yes it is: that I'm sure of <http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp>

Comment: you can check the script at [this page](http://copot.eu/matei/account/account-scripts.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it:

first, i suggest you to avoid inlined javascript events.

Replace this line : `<input type='button' id="createNewAccount" value='Create Account' />`

Your 'bug' was with the data-type from the input:text fields. Replace them for `.val()` instead of `.html()`

```
if (localStorage.hasAnAccount) {
    $('#signup').hide();
    $('#AccountName').html(localStorage.accountName)
} else {
    $('#account').hide();
}


/* run your fonctionnality upon the id of your button */
$('#createNewAccount').click(

function () {
    /* replace .html() by .val() */
        localStorage.accountName = $('#newAccountName').val();
    /* replace .html() by .val() */
        localStorage.accountPassword = $('newAccountPassword').val();

    /* this next testing will not validate for alphanumeric */
    if (typeof localStorage.accountName == 'string' && typeof localStorage.accountPassword == 'string') {

        alert('congrats! Your account has been made!');
        localStorage.hasAnAccount = true;
    } else {
        alert('check that your name and password are alphanumeric strings');
    }
});
```

[jsfiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/7WXue/1/)
and a [version with a 'clearStorage' button](http://jsfiddle.net/7WXue/2/) to play.

Just to mention:

- you have to re-run the script on jsFiddle to see it applied.
- you have javascript errors on your page (ReferenceError: barHeight is not defined
  Source : http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/scripts.js  Line : 33) witch blocks the rest of the scripting.

Comment: so I should change as well the button id to createNewAccount right? And shouldn't wrap it in document.write... let me try...

And btw, localStorage is server or client side?

Comment: sorry... doesn't work: I loaded the file on the website: you can check yourself!

Comment: The jsFiddle provided works correctly. Look on left column of jsFiddle, the scripting is wraped in DOMready.

Comment: Strange: doesn't work on my screen, doesn't hide #account if you have no account and doesn't hide #signup when you should have one... are you sure?

Comment: Good luck with the rest of your site Matei Copot, all i could do for you and this question is written within my answer. If you read it carefully, you'll notice i flagued a javascript error on your site interfering with it's behavior.

Comment: I reuploaded the files on the server with what you told me to update (+the document.write): does it work there? And thanks a lot: mail me if you ever want to help with the website in general

Comment: In the logs right? It says that access to local storage is denied for that document... how do I change that?

Comment: Matei, you confirmed that your page add access to localStorage in a previous comment "@Milkywayspatterns it runs the alert: I checked" and now it doesn't. ??? Maybe you should fix one thing at the time with one question at the time. I am willing to help over Stackoverflow with the normal processing of things, one question and one answer. I will leave you some time to fix your other issues and come back 2morrow. If you have another issue that blocks you, i will give another try from there.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot: I know it's strange and I'm as confused as you, see you tomorrow

Comment: @Cicada3301 This this part answered your question? If so, mark it has accepted if not, wait a little to see what the rest of the community can provide.

Comment: It doesn't block the rest of the script: it's in a function that I don't trigger anywhere... I'll remove it anyway..